# Css font-face using ttc file

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

This is my first time using font-face, and it's really hard for me to actually render the exact font, especially when it comes to `*.ttc` files.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontName';
    src: url('../fonts/font.ttc') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
}


.header {
    font-family: 'FontName;
}
```

When I check the network tab in Chrome's inpector, I can see that the font is loaded successfully, but the result text still uses another font.

What did I do wrong? Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks a lot in advance.

**Update**

One more thing that I figured out. When I style inline, the font is rendered correctly.

```
    <p style="font-family:'FontName'">test 2</p>
```

Is there any delay in loading or something like that?

Comment: You forgot @import before font-face declaration

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use font collections for CSS `@font-face` declarations as the purpose of this syntax is to, *unambiguously*, specify which single font resource must be used by the browser when you specify some *specific* combination of font-{family, weight, style, etc} in your actual page CSS.

Specifying a font collection makes this impossible: there is no syntax to specify which font inside that collection you would need, so `ttc` are not supported by design. Extract the individual font assets you need (*if legally allowed!*) and then be explicit about which single font you need for which single `@font-face` declaration.

And remember that this is possible:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myfont;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('that-font-I-like-Regular.woff') format('WOFF');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: myfont;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url('that-font-I-like-Regular.woff') format('WOFF');
}

...

:root {
  font-family: myfont;
}   

h1 {
  font-weight: normal; /* will use that-font-I-like-Regular.woff */
  ...
}

p {
  font-weight: bold; /* will _also_ use that-font-I-like-Regular.woff */
  ...
}
```

Comment: If `font-weight: bold` really uses `that-font-I-like-Regular.woff` then an explanation as to why would be good. If it's a typo please correct.

Comment: thusly corrected.

Comment: The [MDN documentation for `@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) states you can use a fragment identifier to signify a single font in a container: *If the font file is a container for multiple fonts, a fragment identifier is included to indicate which sub-font should be used, as follows*, where the fragment identifier is the PostScript name of the font. This seems to contradict your claim that there is no syntax to select a single font from a collection.

Comment: That's not to say that there is *browser* support for collections; Firefox [certainly doesn't yet](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1529652), and, I am unsure if Chrome does (but I can't find an official reference for this yet).

Comment: Are we looking at the same page? That MDN page does not have the words "container" or "multiple" in it anywhere? (it has a link to `@container` but that's entirely unrelated)

Comment: (The draft for CSS4's font module has text to that effect, over on https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-fonts/#font-face-src-loading, but w3c drafts carry zero weight, and can be retracted without notice. So: if and until that draft becomes a TR, there is officially no way to use truetype and opentype collections in CSS)