# Why won't the font change in the website with this HTML code?

Tags: html, web, fonts

Apologies for how simple this question likely is, this is my first time using HTML. I'm trying to build a website for a school project and use the font "Angsana New" but it's not changing. I'm using W3School for the project if that changes anything.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Angsana New';
                src: url('Angsana.ttc');
            }

            .black-box {
                width: 1368px;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .angsana-text {
                font-family: 'Angsana New', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 400;
                color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="black-box"></div> 
        <p class="angsana-text">P  R  I  T  C  H</p>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm honestly not sure where to even start for this, but I've tried various file paths and accessing from different browsers (incase browser compatibility is the problem). I have also asked chatgpt, which hasn't helped.

Any help is greatly appreciated ty:)

Comment: The way your code is, you need to have the font file `Angsana.ttc` in the same folder as your html page and the server must be configured to serve the file. Is this so ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I totally missed that, thanks so much!

Comment: Also, keep in mind `.ttc` font collections are not supported by most browsers (there might be experimental support). See also ["Css font-face using ttc file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143065/css-font-face-using-ttc-file)

Answer (score 0):

The

```
src: url('Angsana.ttc');
```

rule means that you have a file called **Angsana.ttc** at the basepath, which is likely near your HTML file. The first thing to check is whether this file exists there and whether there are privileges for the user operating your server to access it.

The

```
font-family: 'Angsana New';
```

means that you need to have a font family by the name of `Angsana New`.